# .Net Installer repair option

Tags: c#, installation

I am working on a project, where I need to give a repair/remove option to my installer [which will be shown at installation time] if the program previously installed. And I need to do it with VS 2008. Please help me on that.

EDIT: Actually for some security reason I removing registry entry for previous installation. So that I can uninstall it from my application only, which is password protected. So thats why I need to customize that repair/remove option. So that it will appear by seeing some specific registry value. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already start with your setup project? The repair option should be there by default.

Comment: When you remove your product from the MSI database the installer by default will not know that your product already has been installed and just re-installs the application. That is no different than the repair in most cases.

Comment: @0xA3: At the time of overwriting [From Program Files] its giving error in Vista.

Comment: Actually I want to know how can I customize my installation so that I can give a extra window.

Comment: You shouldn't mess with the MSI setting. As you don't describe in detail what you are removing from the Registry I assume you leave the MSI database in a corrupted state. Anyway, there are better ways preventing uninstallation then asking for trouble like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a Setup project to your current solution. A setup project uses the Windows Installer technology which gives you the repair and remove option for free. Use this type of project when you have a "simple" installation. If you want more control (custom dialogs) you should install [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It plugs into VS and you can define an installation file in XML which is then compiled to a Windows Installer package.

Comment: Use Wix, it should be able to handle your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe WIX is more suitable for your requirements where you have more control over your installer.

If you only want your application to be uninstalled only from your application, you can probably add a custom action (or Condition) in your installer which validates if the installer action (Repair/Remove) was launched from your application and not from ARP.

One way would to be pass a Custom Property from your application to the msiexec which is tested in your custom action (or Condition) and doesn't let the installer process proceed if executed without setting this property.